# Jetty 11 - HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 upgrade, how to write the handler?

Tags: java, jetty, http2

I am confused because of the upgrade from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 while using Jetty 11.

AFAIK, HTTP/2 uses `stream`, but in case, the request has been upgrade from 1.1 to 2, and the `curl` also tell

> Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0

But, on the other hand, the `handler` is implemented as below (According to the documentation of Jetty)

```java
public class DummyHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request jettyRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        jettyRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK_200);
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(
            "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "  <title>Jetty Hello World Handler</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "  <p>Hello World</p>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>"
        );
    }
}
```

So, which means the `request` and `response` is still HTTP/1.1, and do not get any benefits from the upgrading from 1.1 to 2 because the above code was not dealing with the `stream` of HTTP2.

My question is how to write the `handler` which handle the HTTP2 (After upgrade) or how to write a handler to deal with HTTP2 request? I checked the document of Jetty but can not find any clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 layers of HTTP: a *semantic* layer, where applications write their logic, and a *transport* layer where the HTTP semantic is converted from/to bytes and travels over the network.

The `Handler` above is at the semantic layer.

This means that requests may be received in either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2, but the received bytes are then converted into a `HttpServletRequest` object and passed to the `Handler.handle(...)` method.

Likewise, what you write in the `HttpServletResponse` object (either headers or body content) will be converted by Jetty transparently into either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.

Typically applications should only work with the semantic layer, because in this way they work for both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

You can configure Jetty to accept both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 on the same network port; HTTP/2 compliant clients will talk to Jetty in HTTP/2, and Jetty will then call your `Handler`; old clients that do not support HTTP/2 will use HTTP/1.1 and Jetty will still call the same `Handler`.

If you really want to deal with HTTP/2 frames, Jetty offers the low-level HTTP/2 APIs, documented [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http2).

In summary, your `Handler` above is already what you need to handle HTTP/2 requests (and also HTTP/1.1 requests), provided you have configured Jetty correctly.